# 2-way/Mutual SSL Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, xamarin.ios, pfx

I am trying to implement a mutual SSL between an iOS app (Xamarin) and a Tableau server.  The app is simply pulling Tableau viz into a WkWebView.  I did my google-fu but there's almost next to nothing on that subject.  The closest thing I came across is using a .NET httpclient to handle all the network communication.  Here's the [link](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/HttpClient).  I just wonder there's a more native/delegate approach in Xamarin, using Webkit, i.e. WkNavigationDelegate, to achieve 2-way SSL?

Comment: By *2 way SSL* you likely mean **TLS with client-side certificates**. That should give you a lot more hits on google. `WKWebView` will work with any client certificate that is installed on the iOS device (keychain).

Comment: I have tried the TLS with client-side cert search.   I still have trouble grasping the concept well enough to write an implementation in Xamarin.iOS, using NSURLSession.  The client cert is in a pfx format.  Any pointers, perhaps blogs, forums, etc, would be greatly appreciated...many thanks in advance